# How properly configure/form request for NSFetchedResultsController to include Many-To-Many relation?

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

We have a classic many-to-many relation between entities Product and Category, where one Product may be contained in many Categories. We'd like to show this in the UI using NSFetchedResultsController with UITableViewController or UICollectionView where Category.name would be a Section header text/title and Product.name would be Cell text.

How to configure the NSFetchedResultsController and sectionKeyName for it so we could get Products grouped by Category, considering that Product may be included in multiple Categories?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. One way to do this would be to define the entity of your fetched results controller to be the product-categories link table. In other words, every entry in your table is a product-category combination, which allows a product to appear multiple times in your table. Then you'll use the category info to define sections and product info to define cells. Your sectionKeyPath will be something like `category.name`.

Comment: Currently we don't have product-categories link table defined in core-data. I mean core-data creates it automatically in the sqlite database but I didn't define entity for it.

Comment: Yeah, that's interesting. I can't say for sure, but denormalizing your data and creating that table may be the easiest way to solve this.